# Any software-tool off-line to create LaTeX text as a graph?

Tags: graphics

I like to make math graphs, with Mathematica, with Adobe Fireworks, with Hypersnap etc. However I have a problem, because I would like to have a plugin to Adobe Fireworks or HyperSnap, to enter LaTeX code, like I enter normal text *ABC...abc...*.

Is it possible? I know about an on-line equation editor [Sciweavers](http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor) but it´s a little slow, and I prefer off-line tools.

Instead I'm looking for something like [LaTeX en Inkscape con TeXText](http://www.tec-digital.itcr.ac.cr/revistamatematica/Secciones/Didactica_y_Software/RevistaDigital_Walter_V13_n2_2013/index.html) but I prefer Adobe Fireworks & Hypersnap to InkScape.

The other feasible way for me is to code LaTeX in WinEdt and obtain a graph with transparent background. Is it also possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of our site.

Comment: If you really want Adobe Fireworks you can create the `eps` files and insert some tags to be replaced by LaTeX commands using `psfrag`.

Comment: @Sigur is possible an example?

Comment: @Peter-Jansson Jansson What´s the difference between that web and this web?

Comment: If you mean TeX and TeX meta? then meta is for discussion about TeX.sx and where you can find discussions on how issues on TeX.sx should be handled. All sites on stackexchange have an associated meta site